# Installing Docker with script on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, installation

I'm attempting to create/find a script that downloads and installs docker on windows.
Does this already exist or is it not possible?

Answer (score 2):

Here the steps I am using to install Docker CE on my Windows 10. An example with Powershell commands.

```
# First Download the installer (wget is slow...)
# wget https://download.docker.com/win/stable/Docker%20for%20Windows%20Installer.exe -OutFile docker-installer.exe

(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://download.docker.com/win/stable/Docker%20for%20Windows%20Installer.exe', 'docker-installer.exe')

# Install
start-process -wait docker-installer.exe " install --quiet"

# Clean-up
rm docker-installer.exe

# Run
start-process "$env:ProgramFiles\docker\Docker\Docker for Windows.exe"

write-host "Done."
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing Docker Engine on Windows Server 2016 is two commands and simple to script:

```
Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force
Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider
```

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-server